# Add a custom text to specific email notification for local pickup Woocommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I tried the following code that is displaying a message to all those customers who should receive a `customer_processing_order` and `customer_completed_order` when `local_pickup` is the chosen shipping method.

I noticed I do not store any _shipping_method item within any order meta, but only a thing like: order_item_type: shipping > method_id > `local_pickup:3`

How can I retrieve it?

I tried this of code without success:

```
// testo per Ritiro in Sede

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_completed_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function my_completed_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

if( 'customer_processing_order' != $email->id ) return;

if ( method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
} else {
    $order_id = $order->id;
}

$shipping_method_arr = get_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_method', false); 
$method_id = explode( ':', $shipping_method_arr[0][0] );
$method_id = $method_id[0];  // We get the slug type method


if ( 'local_pickup' == $method_id ){
    echo '<p><strong>Ritiro in sede</strong></p>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done iterating through order shipping items, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_completed_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function my_completed_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for processing and completed email notifications to customer
    if( ! ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id || 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ){
        $shipping_rate_id = $shipping_item->get_method_id();
        $method_array = explode(':', $shipping_rate_id );
        $shipping_method_id = reset($method_array);
        // Display a custom text for local pickup shipping method only
        if( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ){
            echo '<p><strong>Ritiro in sede</strong></p>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: @alemarengo Sorry I was tired and when renaming and writing on here after testing I have maid typos… As it works now, you could remove those 2 comments please, that are not anymore necessary. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Works great. Thank you, @LoicTheAztec!