# Custom email notification for local shipping and completed orders only in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, shipping-method

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712815/add-a-custom-text-to-specific-email-notification-for-local-pickup-woocommerce-or?answertab=active#tab-top) code (which does work) in a previous thread which enables custom messages for e-mail to customers who've selected local pickup as shipping method.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 
'my_completed_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function my_completed_order_email_instructions( $order, 
$sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
// Only for processing and completed email notifications to customer
if( ! ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id || 
'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) ) return;

foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ){
    $shipping_rate_id = $shipping_item->get_method_id();
    $method_array = explode(':', $shipping_rate_id );
    $shipping_method_id = reset($method_array);
    // Display a custom text for local pickup shipping method only
    if( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ){
        echo '<p><strong>Ritiro in sede</strong></p>';
        break;
    }
}
```

**Now to my question:** How do I adjust the code to remove the processing order e-mail so it only covers completed order e-mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace in the function code this:

```
// Only for processing and completed email notifications to customer
if( ! ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id || 
'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) ) return;
```

by this:

```
// Only for completed email notifications to customer
if( 'customer_completed_order' != $email->id ) return;
```

And it will work only for "completed" order notification to the customer… So the complete code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_completed_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function my_completed_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for completed email notifications to customer
    if( 'customer_completed_order' != $email->id ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ){
        $shipping_rate_id = $shipping_item->get_method_id();
        $method_array = explode(':', $shipping_rate_id );
        $shipping_method_id = reset($method_array);
        // Display a custom text for local pickup shipping method only
        if( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ){
            echo '<p><strong>Ritiro in sede</strong></p>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Related: [Add a custom text to specific email notification for local pickup Woocommerce orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712815/add-a-custom-text-to-specific-email-notification-for-local-pickup-woocommerce-or/47713767#47713767)